# I'm trying to load all the images as a scrollable menu but can't figure out how

Tags: react-native, jsx

I'm new to react native, I am trying to get a menu composed of logos that someone could just scroll down then tap one to go into more detail about it.

So I have my `App.js` file like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Image,
  ScrollView,
  Text
} from 'react-native';

import getImageForRestaurant from './utils/getImageForRestaurant';
import Avatar from './components/Avatar';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      restaurants: 'buffalo',
    };
  }

  render() {
    const {
      restaurants
    } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={styles.appContainer}>
        <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>Title</Text>
      </View>
        <ScrollView style={styles.timerlist}>
          <Avatar
            initials="KC"
            size={75}
            source={getImageForRestaurant(restaurants)}
            backgroundColor={'blue'}
            onPressLinkImage={() => {
              console.log('Pressed!');
            }}
          />
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  appContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  titleContainer: {
    paddingTop: 35,
    paddingBottom: 15,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: '#D6D7DA',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  timerList: {
    paddingBottom: 15,
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#34495E',
  },
  imageContainer: {
    flex: 0,
  },
  image: {
    flex: 1,
    width: 75,
    height: 75,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
  },
});
```

The `getImageForRestaurant()` method works as intended if I make it inside an `<Image/>` but if I try to make it the `source` of my "Avatar" component then it won't work.

My `getImageForRestaurant.js` file is just this:

```
const images = {
  buffalo1: require('../assets/restaurants/logo1.jpeg'),
  buffalo: require('../assets/restaurants/logo2.png'),
  buffalo2: require('../assets/restaurants/logo3.jpeg'),
};

export default restaurants => images[restaurants];
```

And finally my `Avatar.js` is as follows:

```
import {
  ColorPropType,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';

import getImageForRestaurant from '../utils/getImageForRestaurant';

export default function Avatar({
  size,
  backgroundColor,
  initials,
  source,
  onPressLinkImage,
}) {
  const style = {
    width: size,
    height: size,
    borderRadius: size / 2,
    backgroundColor,
  };

  return (
    <View style={[styles.container, style]}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPressLinkImage}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{initials}</Text>
        <Image source={require(getImageForRestaurant(source))} />
        {/*<Image source={require("../assets/restaurants/logo1.jpeg")} />*/}
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

Avatar.propTypes = {
  initials: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  size: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  source: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  backgroundColor: ColorPropType.isRequired,
  onPressLinkImage: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    color: 'white',
  },
});
```

So if I just do an Image source, (the commented part) it works as a regular image, but then I need to hard-code the actual url and what I want is to just load all images one next to the other in a scrollable grid. Haven't been able to figure out how to do what I want. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: You double `require(require(...))` the image source. Just make it to <Image source={getImageForRestaurant(source)} />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Edison makes a good point about good practices, I believe your problem is that you are just requiring the image twice. The output of the require() is what you need to pass to the Image component. You are doing require of a require.

```
<Image source={require(getImageForRestaurant(source))} />
```

Probably just changing to this should work:

```
<Image source={getImageForRestaurant(source)} />
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s a bad practice to generate url inside the source prop. Always make sure that the necessary URL is built before its passed inside source prop. You can use a variable to build your URL and then pass it to source prop. (In your case, image is imported inside helper function and hence I will use image variable)

```
 const image = getImageforRestaurant(source)

 <Image source={image} />
```

When you want to load images from the internet do it like this.

```
const link = ‘http://example.com/image.png’

<Image source={{uri: link}} />
```